# Setting the power spectral density from a file

Tags: bilby

How does one set the power spectral density (PSD) from file and is it possible to use a different PSD for generating the data and for likelihood evaluation?

Question asked by Vivien Raymond by email.

Answer (score 1):

### Setting the PSD from file

To set the PSD from a file, first initialise a list of interferometers, here we just use Hanford:

```py
>>> ifos = bilby.gw.detector.InterferometerList(['H1'])
```

Every element of the list is initialised with a default PSD using the advanced LIGO noise curve, to check this

```py
>>> ifos[0].power_spectral_density
PowerSpectralDensity(psd_file='/home/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bilby-0.3.5-py3.6.egg/bilby/gw/noise_curves/aLIGO_ZERO_DET_high_P_psd.txt', asd_file='None')
```

Note, no data has yet been generated. To overwrite the PSD,simply create a new `PowerSpectralDensity` object and assign it (if you have multiple detectors, you'll need to do this for every element of the list)

```py
ifos[0].power_spectral_density = bilby.gw.detector.PowerSpectralDensity(psd_file=PATH_TO_FILE)
```

Nest, generate an instance of the strain data from the PSD:

```
ifos.set_strain_data_from_power_spectral_densities(
    sampling_frequency=4096, duration=4,
    start_time=-3)
```

You can check what the data looks like by doing

```py
ifos[0].plot_data()
```

[image]

Note, you can also inject signals using the `ifos.inject_signal` method.

### Using a different PSD for likelihood evaluation

Each ifo in the `ifos` list contains both the data and a PSD (or equivalent ASD). For inference, we pass that list into the `bilby.gw.GravitationalWaveLikelihood` object as the first argument and the PSD for each element of the list is used in calculating the likelihood.

So, if you want to use a different PSD for likelihood estimate. First generate the data (as above). Then, assign the PSD you want to use for sampling to each element of `ifos` and pass that object into the likelihood instead. This won't overwrite the data (provided you don't call `set_strain_data_from_power_spectral_densities` of course).